# How to get global references from a vite lib build

Tags: javascript, vite

I will try to start with an example that works.
If I want to refer or get code intellisense from a lib a an arbitrary js file that use global I can simply use the /// (triple dash). Like in `<reference path="../jquery.js"/>` now I can see all types as if it is a global.

I am outputting umd and es. either way would be fine.

For example I have a umd/es build that exports two functions: 'addData' 'getData'
How can I have a reference to those from an file without importing the actual lib? same as we can do with the ///<reference for JQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone wondering the same.

You can define your own d.ts files and put the file in your package.json.
In my case I created a file index.d.ts in the src folder which I also copy to the dist when building.

and in the package.json:
`"types": "./path/index.d.ts"`